# Laravel cookie::forget doesn't work?

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-4

I have this code:

```
Cookie::forget('vendor');
return Redirect::route('vendor_login');
```

What it is supposed to do, is remove the vendor cookie and redirect you to the login page. However, it doesn't actually delete the cookie. From my understanding, I would expect it to send a setcookie header for vendor with a value of null and a negative time. It doesn't send the setcookie header at all. Why is this?

This works perfectly:

```
Cookie::queue('paddle_vendor', null, -1);
return Redirect::route('vendor_login');
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use `queue` method like this:

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('vendor'));
return Redirect::route('vendor_login');
```

Which in this way it allows you to delete multiple cookies at once too.
For more information checkout this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33724308/247670

Or do it like this as [Antonio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23063332/247670) said:

```
$cookie = Cookie::forget('vendor');
return Redirect::route('vendor_login')->withCookie($cookie);
```

Answer (score 5):

You still need to send it with your response:

```
$cookie = Cookie::forget('vendor');

return Redirect::route('vendor_login')->withCookie($cookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

The default laravel

```
  Cookie::queue(
   Cookie::forget('name')
      ) ;
```

Should work perfectly fine if you have not done any changes on your 
      session.php 
        config file. 
Check it out and you should be good to go.