# How to forget all cookies in laravel?

Tags: php, cookies, laravel

Does anyone know if there's a way to forget all cookies (well, all for my web app) in Laravel? I know that I can get rid of one by doing `Cookie::forget('mycookie')` but what if I have a dozen or so, and I want to forget them all?

Is there a simple one-line command like `Cookie::forgetAll()` or something? Or do I just need to loop through all my cookies and forget them one by one?

Thanks!

PS - I'm using Laravel 4.1.28 but would happily update to the latest version if it will make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Laravel source code (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ef0864242e6e6f19a78f941b0710c844016ddf6e/src/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieJar.php), there doesn't seem to be a function to delete all the cookies at once, so you only option would indeed be to loop over all the cookies and delete them one by one.

Comment: Understood. Such is life - I guess I'll just have to loop. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 7):

For deleting multiple cookies at once you can simply do the following and of course you can put it in a loop:

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('key1'));
Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('key2'));
return $myResponse;
```

By doing this, there's also no need to return your response with the cookie object anymore.

`queue()` method queues up the result with cookies and adds them to the header of the request. It doesn't matter you're creating cookies or deleting them. It just works either way!

Also checkout this post here:
https://coderwall.com/p/3etfgw/deleting-cookies-in-laravel

Thanks to [JP Camara](https://twitter.com/jpcamara) for such a great post.

Answer (score 1):

you must to loop over all the cookies and delete them one by one.

```
public function logout(){
        $array = array();
        foreach (Cookie::get() as $key => $item){
            $array []= cookie($key, null, -2628000, null, null);
        }
        return back()->withCookies($array);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on to @Ali answer, one will need to enable the AddQueuedCookiesToResponse middleware

```
protected $middleware = [
        ...
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    ];
```

Alternative 2:
I prefer not to use global middleware since this will run for every single request. It can be achieved by using multiple `withCookie`

```php
        $cookie1 = Cookie::forget('laravel_token');
        $cookie2 = Cookie::forget('laravel_session');

        return response()->json($mydata, $response)
            ->withCookie($cookie1)
            ->withCookie($cookie2);
```